# CSS layout with left column fixed and right column fluid?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

Is there a solid cross browser solution for fixed and fluid CSS columns? I need one column to be fixed on the left hand side, and another column to be fluid on the right hand side.

Below is a snippet of my code - `.promoImg` and `.promoContent` float alongside one another. `#recommends` is 90% of the browser width, `.promoImg` needs to fix at 120px and I'd like the `.promoContent` to stretch fluid.

```
<div class="promoBlock ">
    <div class="promoImg">
        fixed content 300px
    </div>
    <div class="promoContent">
        fluid content
    </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
.promoBlock { width:90%; margin:auto; } 
.promoImg { width:300px; float:left; background-color:red; }
.promoContent { margin-left:300px; background-color:green; }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/P4RBj/

P.S: Didn't get ***promoblock needs to fix at 120px***. If so, your inner div is wider (300px).

Comment: cheers for that - simple and works a treat - sorry (regarding the promoblock quote) I mistyped above - I've now corrected the text